# Date Conversion 24 hours and 12 hours - Kotlin

Tags: android, date, datetime, kotlin, datetime-format

I am getting below date from in UTC format from the server :

**2021-05-20 09:14:55**

Now, I have to convert it into local with 24 hours format and 12 hours format as well.

To convert it into 24 hours format I have done as below :

```
val df = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH)
df.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
val date = df.parse(dataDate)
df.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
val formattedDate = df.format(date)
```

and got the result as : **2021-05-20 14:44:55** (24 hour local)

Now, I have tried to convert same date to local with 12 hour format as below :

```
val utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
val inputFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                Locale.ENGLISH)
inputFormat.timeZone = utc
val outputFormat: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa",
                Locale.ENGLISH)
outputFormat.timeZone = utc
val dateInput = inputFormat.parse(dataDate)
val output = outputFormat.format(dateInput)
```

It give me output as **2021-05-20 09:14:55 AM** (12 hour local)

I think this is wrong its just adding AM as suffix. This might be wrong because If 24 hour date result is **2021-05-20 14:44:55** then 12 hour date result should be **2021-05-20 02:44:55 PM**

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `TimeZone.getDefault()` to print the 24H format, and `TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")` to print the 12H format.

```
df.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
val formattedDate = df.format(date)
```

```
outputFormat.timeZone = utc
val output = outputFormat.format(dateInput)
```

`TimeZone.getDefault()` uses your local time zone, which is not UTC in this case.
Use local timezone for 12H format just like 24H format.

```
outputFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
```

Comment: Whoooo thanks buro. sry for silly mistake.